# What happens to local static identifiers in __init function?

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, static, linux-device-driver

In application programming, `static` variables are stored in `.BSS` section. And ***unlike*** local variables they're not de allocated on function return or something similar to global variables.

---

In Linux kernel modules, functions can be tagged with `__init` attribute in Linux and code in `.text` of such functions will be removed, **once** they're executed.

---

**Let's say there's a function with `__init` and has `static` local variables; Will those `static` local's be de allocated from `.BSS` section along with the function from `.text` section?**

Yes, of course there might not be any use *(mention if you find one)* of declaring a `static` variable in an `__init` function, but I want to understand behind the scenes.

Comment: There's definitely no use for them. Local static variables are for remembering something between calls to the function, but if the function can only be called once there's no point. I suppose the compiler could optimize this to treat them as auto variables.

Comment: But if they don't do that optimization, I'd expect the variables to be treated just like any other local static variable, and stored in either BSS or DATA depending on whether they're zero-initialized or explicitly initialized. I don't think these sections allow for deallocation.

Comment: They will be removed altogether independently if there were executed once, twice or none times. Removal is orthogonal to the fact of execution.

Answer (score 2):

If something is defined as `static`, it must stay alive for the entire lifetime of the associated unit. The only thing that happens is that you will not be able to reference the object by its original name anywhere outside the function in which it was declared. Therefore, if you don't save a reference to the object somewhere else, the object will still be available, but you will have lost access to it (this could be considered a memory leak).

The only exception when talking about kernel code is the `__initdata` macro, that will put variables in a specific section (`.init.data`) and discard them when the initialization is done (just like `.init`). In such case, the variable will be gone even if defined `static`, and references will become invalid. This is useful if you need some kind of complex (and large) structure only for initialization purposes and you want to save space by discarding it after using it in your init function.

Here's a working example:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
#include <linux/init.h>   // module_{init,exit}()
#include <linux/module.h> // THIS_MODULE, MODULE_VERSION, ...
#include <linux/kernel.h> // printk(), pr_*()

#ifdef pr_fmt
#undef pr_fmt
#endif
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt

static unsigned *global_ptr;
static unsigned global_var;
static int global_initdata_var __initdata;

static int __init my_init(void)
{
        static unsigned local_var = 123;
        static unsigned local_initdata_var __initdata = 456;

        global_ptr = &local_var;
        global_var = local_initdata_var;

        return global_initdata_var;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
        pr_info("%u %u\n", *global_ptr , global_var);
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Test module.");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Marco Bonelli");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Looking into the `.ko` file with `objdump` after compiling the above shows:

- `local_var` defined inside the init function in the `.data` section (because it was explicitly initialized to `123`).
- `local_initdata_var`  and `global_initdata_var` in the `.init.data` section (because of `__initdata`), regardless of where they were defined.
- Global non-explicitly initialized variables in the `.bss` section.

```
/ # objdump -j .init.data -j .data -j .bss -D static_init.ko

static_init.ko:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <local_var.20642>:
   0:   0000007b        .word   0x0000007b

Disassembly of section .init.data:

0000000000000000 <local_initdata_var.20643>:
   0:   000001c8        .word   0x000001c8

0000000000000004 <global_initdata_var>:
   4:   00000000        .word   0x00000000

Disassembly of section .bss:

0000000000000000 <global_ptr>:
        ...

0000000000000008 <global_var>:
   8:   00000000        .word   0x00000000
```

Result of inserting/removing the module:

```
/ # insmod static_init.ko
/ # cat /proc/kallsyms | grep static_init
ffff800011ad9768 b static_init_done.7337
ffff800008ca0000 t $x   [static_init]
ffff800008ca0000 t my_exit      [static_init]
ffff800008ca2000 d $d   [static_init]
ffff800008ca2000 d local_var.20642      [static_init]
ffff800008ca2348 b $d   [static_init]
ffff800008ca2348 b global_ptr   [static_init]
ffff800008ca2350 b global_var   [static_init]
ffff800008ca1028 r $d   [static_init]
ffff800008ca2040 d $d   [static_init]
ffff800008ca1040 r $d   [static_init]
ffff800008ca1040 r _note_6      [static_init]
ffff800008ca2040 d __this_module        [static_init]
ffff800008ca0000 t cleanup_module       [static_init]
/ # rmmod static_init
[   12.155152] static_init: 123 456
/ #
```

As you can see, `local_var` is still there even after inserting the module, and is marked as `d` (local data symbol), while variables defined with `__initdata` (no matter where) are no longer there.

Comment: Declaring the variable as `static unsigned static_var __initdata = 123;` will put it in the `.init.data` section, allowing it to be discarded after loading the module. Of course, the `ref` variable will no longer be pointing to anywhere valid then, so the `pr_info("%u\n", *ref);` call in the `my_exit` function will crash.

Comment: That's good to know, I was unaware of `__initdata`. I'll update above, thank you.